# Solving a ODE system with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am having trouble solving a question.

The question is: Determine the general solution of the ODE system
$$\dot{x_1} - 2x_1 + x_2 = e^{2t}$$
$$\dot{x_2} + x_1 - 2x_2 = 2e^{2t}$$

I am trying to solve this by using the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$ and finding the associated eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I have found the eigenvalues to be $\lambda$ = -1 and $\lambda$ = -3. The eigenvectors are $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ respectfully. I found the complementary solution to be $\dot{x_c}$ = A$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$ + B$\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}e^{-3t}$.

We see that the forcing term is not proportional to either of the complementary solutions so we need to find a particular solution of the form $\dot{x_p}$ = **C**$e^{2t}$. I'm stuck at this point and don't know how to find **C**. My thinking is I need to find a matrix such that (Matrix M)**C**$e^{2t}$ = **b**$e^{2t}$ where **b** = $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Hence (Matrix M) **C** = **b** and I can find **C** using row reduction on Matrix M. My problem is I can't find such a matrix to satisfy the equation. I don't know how to progress from this point.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I have copied the question which states it as $\dot{x_1}$ and $\dot{x_2}$, even then how would writing it as ${x_1}'$ and ${x_2}'$ change it?

Comment: I think what you mean is to find the eigenvalues you do **A** + $\lambda$ **I** where **A** is a given matrix and **I** is the identity matrix. I am aware of this method but I have been taught instead to do **A** - $\lambda$ **I**. Hence why my eigenvalues being the negative of yours.

Comment: I see what you mean. Even then only the eigenvalues would change, not the eigenvectors unless I am mistaken? In which case I have $e^{t}$ and $e^{3t}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try solutions proportional to $\exp{(2t)}$, $\textit{i.e}$:
$$x_1=c_1\exp{(2t)}$$
$$x_2=c_2\exp{(2t)}$$
To arrive to the system 
$$\left\{2\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}-2&1\\1&-2\end{bmatrix}\right\}\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$$
Solve for $c_1,c_2$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it seems simple enough now that I look at it. I was trying to do it by **I** + **A** and got to $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and was stuck then.

Comment: Forget that you have a system, treat each variable separately, and then form the system (this leads naturally to the eigenvalue system for the homogeneous case).